# Conversão de varchar para float quando a string é vazia e/ou em branco

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Tenho uma coluna onde as strings estão no seguinte formato: "**12,05%**"

Preciso fazer uns cálculos com esses valores, e estou formatando os valores que sejam aceitáveis para o formato float/double etc.

Tenho a seguinte linha em minha consulta:

```
cast(replace(replace(replace(campo, '%', ''), '.', ''), ',', '.') as float)
```

Ela executa conforme o esperado sem problemas, porém essa coluna possui valores nulos ou sem valor, que no caso não têm nenhum numero para que possam ser convertidos pra float e isso acaba gerando um erro, preciso tratar esses valores para que recebam "0".

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal usar a função `translate()` combinada com `nullif()` e `coalesce()`:

```
translate( coalesce( nullif(trim(campo),''), '0,0%') , ',%', '.' )::NUMERIC
```

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  campo TEXT
);


INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 1, NULL ); 
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 2, '' );   
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 3, '   ' );  
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 4, '12,25%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 5, '0,00%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 6, '33,33%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 7, '233,557%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 8, '12.25%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 9, '10.50%' );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, campo ) VALUES ( 10, '33%' );
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT
  campo,
  translate( coalesce( nullif(trim(campo),''), '0,0%') , ',%', '.' )::NUMERIC
FROM
  tb_foobar;
```

Saída:

```
|    campo | translate |
|----------|-----------|
|   (null) |         0 |
|          |         0 |
|          |         0 |
|   12,25% |     12.25 |
|    0,00% |         0 |
|   33,33% |     33.33 |
| 233,557% |   233.557 |
|   12.25% |     12.25 |
|   10.50% |      10.5 |
|      33% |        33 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/406fd/2

Comment: Para algo mais elegante, tentei usar a função `to_number()`, mas não consegui algo mais "limpo" que isso. Alguém ?

Comment: Isso ficou muito bom e funcionou perfeitamente!
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Faça um `UPDATE` na sua tabela

```
UPDATE sua_tabela 
SET campo = '0%' 
WHERE campo = '' OR campo IS NULL
```

Então você terá todos os campos no padrão necessário para seu cast e depois jogar o campo pra float.

Comment: Qual o motivo de ter negativado a resposta? Há algo de errado nela?

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer isso porém eu preciso manter como está, na tabela que possuo, valor '0' e 'sem valor' importa e são diferentes, porém para um cálculo específico, não importa. Mas obrigado, e não fui eu quem negativou, e eu também recebi uma negativação aleatória ._.

Comment: Hmm entendo. Então 0, '' e null são todos diferentes? Ou '' e null são iguais?

Comment: Por exemplo, quando possui "0%", ainda faz o cálculo em outras consultas, mas se possui "" não faz, porém isso é tratado dentro da aplicação usando um equals. Agora estou criando um procedure no banco

Comment: Eu ja tentei algumas funções que possuem na documentação do postgres, como a **coalesce**, mas não funcionou também.

Comment: Entendi, então o ideal é que os que atualmente não tem valor fique um float NULL pra diferenciar dos que existem valor 0 ?

Comment: Sim, exatamente.

Comment: Isso não funciona se o campo possuir espaços em branco.