# Consulta com conversão de Datatype - Varchar para Float

Tags: mysql, sql, conversão-de-tipo

Ao efetuar uma consulta, preciso que uma coluna de uma determinada tabela converter seu *DataType* para `FLOAT`.

**CONFIGURAÇÃO DA COLUNA**
[image: Configuração da Coluna no Banco de Dados]

**Nome:** `16_remuneracao_sem_13`
**DataType:** `VARCHAR(15)`

**REALIZANDO CONSULTA PADRÃO**

```
SELECT `16_remuneracao_sem_13` as 'SALÁRIO' FROM t_trabalhador;
```

**RETORNO:**
[image: RESULTADO DA CONSULTA]

**EXPLICAÇÃO**
Os dados que recebemos como retorno da consulta representam valores monetários. Onde as ultimas duas ultimas caracteres correspondem a duas casas fracionais. Assim sendo o valor `000000000119760` no ato da conversão para ***FLOAT*** precisa ser adicionado a virgula, como resultado obtivemos `0000000001197.60`.

**ADICIONANDO VIRGULA AO VALOR**
Para solucionar o problema da virgula utilizei a query personalizada a baixo.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(`t_trabalhador`.`16_remuneracao_sem_13`, 1, 13), ".",             
SUBSTR(`t_trabalhador`.`16_remuneracao_sem_13`, 14, 2)) as 'SALÁRIO' 
FROM t_trabalhador;
```

**RETORNO**

```
SALÁRIO
0000000006266.00
0000000009310.00
0000000001197.60
0000000001080.00
0000000006266.00
0000000009310.00
0000000001197.60
0000000001080.00
0000000006266.00
```

**COMO RETORNAR A STRING COMO FLOAT**
Eu preciso que o MySQL me retorne o valor da string como float me trazendo como resultado um retorno como segue a baixo.

**RESULTADO PRETENDIDO** 
Lembrando que preciso que o SQL retorne de fato como Float, não posso fazer um replace para substituir os zeros para espaços em branco.

```
SELECT 
0 + CONCAT(SUBSTR(`t_trabalhador`.`16_remuneracao_sem_13`, 1, 13), ".",     
SUBSTR(`t_trabalhador`.`16_remuneracao_sem_13`, 14, 2)) as 'SALÁRIO' 
FROM t_trabalhador;
```

**RETORNO**

```
SALÁRIO
6266
9310
1197.6
1080
6266
9310
1197.6
1080
6266
```

A solução aqui se difere no fato de você poder definir onde vai ficar a virgula na string. Se essa proposta não lhe foi útil der uma olhada nesta outra postagem que tem o mesmo [proposito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297541/convers%C3%A3o-de-varchar-para-float-quando-a-string-%C3%A9-vazia-e-ou-em-branco) mas com uma necessidade mais simples.

Comment: Existe uma maneira mais elegante para realizar esse procedimento?

Comment: A situação aqui é bem mais objetiva do que a proposta nesta postagem.

Answer (score 0):

Testa se assim resolve o teu problema, com recurso à função de MySql TRIM, tens [AQUI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) a documentação.

**Query**

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM `16_remuneracao_sem_13`)+0
FROM `t_trabalhador`;
```